# Is the torsion set of the group of permutations on $\mathbb N$ closed under composition?

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

Let $S(\mathbb N)$ be the permutation group over $\mathbb N$ , then is it true that there exist elements $f,g\in S(\mathbb N)$ of finite order such that $f\circ g$ is not of finite order ?

Comment: My idea: Let $f$ and $g$ each be infinite products of disjoint transpositions.

Answer (score 4):

The map $x\mapsto -x$ and the map $x\mapsto 1-x$ of Z to itself have both finite order and their composition does not. On the other hand, there is a bijection between Z and N. These two facts should help you answer your question.

Comment: Notice that the permutation group of N contains copies of all countable groups (because of Cayley's theorem) so you can simply pick a subgroup isomorphic to the free product of two finite cyclic group, for example.